# MSBuild transitive ProjectReference's content not copied to build output of unit test project

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2019

I have the following (simplified) solution structure:

```
ProjectA
|- Content: myexe.exe with CopyIfNewer

ProjectB
|- ProjRef: ProjectA

ProjectC
|- ProjRef: ProjectB
```

When I run a build of ProjectC where ProjectA is built also (e.g., because ProjectA is not up-to-date, or because I clicked "Rebuild all") then myexe.exe is put into ProjectC's bin output folder. However, in any other case, myexe.exe is NOT in ProjectC's bin output folder.

Is this a known problem? Am I doing something wrong? How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, in any other case, myexe.exe is NOT in ProjectC's bin output
>   folder.
>   Is this a known problem? Am I doing something wrong? How to fix this?

**Test**

First, l guess that the first project is a ,net framework project or even the three projects are based on the framework. In my side, l created such three projects and cited the relationships you mentioned for the three projects.Exactly, when I modified the codes of Project C(**A and B already built before**), the file cannot copy into Project C as you wish. But when l just have two projects A,B(B project reference:A), it always copy the files of the first project A into B(**whenever l choose Copy always or Copy if newer or build or rebuild the project B**). Besides,I tested three projects which are based on Net Core or .Net Standard works without problems.

**Conclusion**

So the reason for this problem is pointed out that the intermediate project, **project B**, is not built（**up-to-date Skips the build** ), so the files of Project A could not be copied to the Project C as the transit station. (especially for non-sdk framework projects). l think it is a feature or issue in Project Reference in Visual Studio. or you could report it to [DC Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) for a detailed explanation.

**Solution**

You can add such property to the csproj file of project B to break the latest check and ensure that it is always built. You can add this node under PropertyGroup both in Debug or Release

```
 <DisableFastUpToDateCheck> true </DisableFastUpToDateCheck>
```

Hope it could help you.

Comment: Thank you. I realized that the problem is even occurring if there is no intermediary project. If ProjectA is not built, the content output is simply not copied to the output of ProjectB! I've created an issue at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/838431/content-not-copied-to-output-of-dependent-project.html

Comment: For now, we use a workaround: we added a PostBuild step to ProjectC which manually copies the content from ProjectA.